# Using html and javascript how do i implement google cloud apikey to sign up daabase

Tags: javascript, html, database, security

I have this code that uses a terminal for a text-based game and i want to create a account and password and saved in a database saved in the cloud of google using a apikey and a folder id

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <title>Text Adventure Game with Google Drive Integration</title>

  <style>

    body {

      display: flex;

      align-items: center;

      justify-content: center;

      height: 100vh;

      margin: 0;

      background-color: #f4f4f4;

      font-family: monospace;

    }

    #game-container {

      background-color: #fff;

      padding: 20px;

      border-radius: 8px;

      box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

      max-width: 400px;

      width: 100%;

    }

    #output {

      white-space: pre-wrap;

      height: 200px;

      overflow-y: auto;

      border: 1px solid #ddd;

      padding: 10px;

      margin-bottom: 10px;

    }

    #input {

      padding: 5px;

      width: 100%;

      border: 1px solid #ddd;

      border-radius: 4px;

      font-family: monospace;

    }

    .command-list {

      list-style-type: none;

      padding: 0;

      margin-bottom: 10px;

    }

    .command-list li {

      display: inline;

      margin-right: 10px;

      cursor: pointer;

    }

    .prompt {

      font-weight: bold;

    }

  </style>

  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="game-container">

    <pre id="output"></pre>

    <div>

      <ul class="command-list">

        <li onclick="insertCommand('start')">start</li>

        <li onclick="insertCommand('quit')">quit</li>

        <li onclick="insertCommand('help')">help</li>

        <li onclick="insertCommand('inventory')">inventory</li>

        <!-- Add more commands here -->

      </ul>

    </div>

    <input type="text" id="input" autofocus/>

  </div>

  <script>

    // Game variables

    const output = document.getElementById('output');

    const input = document.getElementById('input');

    const commandList = document.querySelectorAll('.command-list li');

    let isSigningUp = false;

    let isEnteringUsername = false;

    let username = '';

    let password = '';

    // Initialize Google Drive API

    gapi.load('client', initClient);

    function initClient() {

      gapi.client.init({

        apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY',

        discoveryDocs: ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest'],

      }).then(function() {

        console.log('Google Drive API initialized');

      }).catch(function(error) {

        console.error('Error initializing Google Drive API:', error);

      });

    }

    // Game command processing

    input.addEventListener('keydown', handleInput);

    function handleInput(event) {

      if (event.key === 'Enter') {

        const command = input.value.toLowerCase();

        input.value = '';

        output.textContent += '> ' + command + '\n';

        processCommand(command);

        output.scrollTop = output.scrollHeight;

      }

    }

    function processCommand(command) {

      if (command === 'start') {

        if (!username) {

          output.textContent += 'Welcome to the game!\n';

          output.textContent += 'You need to sign up or sign in first.\n';

          output.textContent += 'To sign up, type "signup".\n';

          output.textContent += 'To sign in, type "signin".\n';

        } else {

          output.textContent += `Welcome back, ${username}!\n`;

          output.textContent += 'Now you can access all the game commands.\n';

          // Unlock other game commands

        }

      } else if (command === 'quit') {

        output.textContent += 'Game ended. Thank you for playing!\n';

        input.disabled = true;

      } else if (command === 'help') {

        output.textContent += 'Available commands:\n';

        output.textContent += '- start: Start the game.\n';

        output.textContent += '- quit: End the game.\n';

        output.textContent += '- help: Show available commands.\n';

        output.textContent += '- inventory: Show your inventory.\n';

        // Add more commands and their descriptions here

      } else if (command === 'inventory') {

        if (username) {

          output.textContent += 'You currently have:\n';

          output.textContent += '- Sword\n';

          output.textContent += '- Shield\n';

          // Add more inventory items or logic here

        } else {

          output.textContent += 'You need to sign up or sign in first.\n';

        }

      } else if (command === 'signup') {

        if (!username && !isSigningUp) {

          isSigningUp = true;

          output.textContent += 'Enter your username:\n';

        } else if (!username && isSigningUp) {

          output.textContent += 'You are already signing up. Enter your username:\n';

        } else {

          output.textContent += 'You are already registered.\n';

        }

      } else if (isSigningUp) {

        if (!username && !isEnteringUsername) {

          isEnteringUsername = true;

          username = command;

          output.textContent += `Username set as: ${username}\n`;

          output.textContent += 'Enter your password:\n';

        } else if (username && !isEnteringUsername) {

          output.textContent += 'You have already set a username.\n';

        } else if (isEnteringUsername) {

          isEnteringUsername = false;

          password = command;

          saveCredentials(username, password);

          output.textContent += 'Registration completed. Now you can sign in. Type "signin" to continue.\n';

          output.innerHTML += '<span class="prompt" onclick="insertCommand(\'signin\')">signin</span> &gt; ';

        }

      } else if (command === 'signin') {

        if (!username) {

          output.textContent += 'Enter your username:\n';

        } else {

          // Search for credentials in the database

          findCredentials(username, password);

        }

      } else {

        output.textContent += 'Sorry, I don\'t understand that command.\n';

      }

    }

    function insertCommand(command) {

      input.value = command;

      input.focus();

    }

    // Function to save credentials to Google Drive

    function saveCredentials(username, password) {

      const credentials = {

        username: username,

        password: password

      };

      const fileMetadata = {

        name: 'game_credentials.json',

        mimeType: 'application/json'

      };

      const fileContent = JSON.stringify(credentials);

      const fileData = new Blob([fileContent], { type: 'application/json' });

      const accessToken = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token;

      const form = new FormData();

      form.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify(fileMetadata)], { type: 'application/json' }));

      form.append('file', fileData);

      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhr.open('post', 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart');

      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);

      xhr.responseType = 'json';

      xhr.onload = function() {

        if (xhr.status === 200) {

          console.log('Credentials saved to Google Drive');

        } else {

          console.error('Error saving credentials to Google Drive:', xhr.response.error);

        }

      };

      xhr.send(form);

    }

    // Function to find credentials in Google Drive

    function findCredentials(username, password) {

      const accessToken = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token;

      const query = "name='game_credentials.json'";

      const params = {

        q: query,

        fields: 'files(id, name, webViewLink)'

      };

      gapi.client.drive.files.list(params).then(function(response) {

        const files = response.result.files;

        if (files && files.length > 0) {

          const fileId = files[0].id;

          const fileLink = files[0].webViewLink;

          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

          xhr.open('GET', `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileId}?alt=media`);

          xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);

          xhr.onload = function() {

            if (xhr.status === 200) {

              const credentials = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

              if (credentials.username === username && credentials.password === password) {

                output.textContent += 'You have successfully signed in.\n';

                output.innerHTML += 'Welcome back! Now you can play.\n';

              } else {

                output.textContent += 'Incorrect username or password.\n';

              }

            } else {

              console.error('Error retrieving credentials file:', xhr.statusText);

            }

          };

          xhr.send();

        } else {

          output.textContent += 'No registered credentials found.\n';

        }

      });

    }

  </script>

  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

So i have create this code in order to try make the html create a .txt file inside the Google drive cloud folder id but it yet hasnt do anything as requested just can fake create a account username and a fake password which wont save in anywhere.
So can somebody find me a solution or a advice of what im doing wrong of course forgetting the fact That im not using sql or any other database thats works for its purposes jajaja its because im studying cibersecurity so first im making a html file with the less security possible and after completing the project i will create a function to make it secure even when its actually not his main purpose all for free

Im just looking for a solution